# Not saving data when add multiple select attribute in product grid

Tags: magento, filter, multi-select

I have created one custom module with add associated products concept. Created successfully. And Its working well.

But when i add "Multi select attribute" column in product grid with that option values, That entity value not saved.

[image]

If i removed that option values from that brand attribute drop down, Its saving fine.

I have shown my code below what i did for add multi select attribute column in product grid

under **_prepareColumns()** method

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'brand');        // attribute code here
foreach ( $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true) as $option)
{
    if($option['value'] != '')
    $valArr[$option['value']] =  $option['label'];
}


$this->addColumn('brand', array(
    'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Brand'),
    'align' => 'left',
    'index' => 'brand',
    'type'  => 'options',
    'options' => $valArr,


   'renderer'  => 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Renderer_Brands', // Will have to create the renderer.
   'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_filterBrandCondition')
));
```

When i hide `'options' => $valArr,` , All are working fine.

I can't able to understand, why its happening. Please suggest me your ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check here for get answer

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/35286/not-saving-data-when-add-multiple-select-attribute-in-product-grid/35421#35421

Answer (score 0):

Have you already created the _filterBrandCondition function ?

What Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Renderer_Brands look like ?

Comment: yeah... I have created filter function named "_filterBrandCondition"
 Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Renderer_Brands - Created it for renderer. I have fixed this issue. Please check above comment